# How to convert TIMESTAMP into String in Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate

I would like to compare date in Hibernate query. In my database data is in `TIMESTAMP` but my input in string so I would like to convert `TIMESTAMP` to string and compare my date.

```
List<User> usersList = session.createQuery("from User where CAST(DATE(created_date) as CHAR)=2015-01-19").list();
```

This is working in MySQL but not in Hibernate, please give me solution for this issue.

Comment: Apparently the field is a date in the database, so why not just convert the string you have into a proper Date object and shove that into the query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SimpleDateFormat here

First create Date object from timestamp

```
Date  createdDateTemp= new Date(timestamMillis);
```

Using  SimpleDateFormat convert date in to formated string

```
String createdDateString = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(createdDateTemp));
```

now your HQL query will look like below

```
List<User> usersList=session.createQuery("from User where :createdDate = 2015-01-19").setParameter("createdDate", createdDateString).list();
```